# Error: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

I am doing my python assignment, but there is an error when I wanted to test the case above.

Here is my code:

```
def evalTerm(env, t):
    if type(t) == Node:
        for label in t:
            children = t[label]
            if label == 'Number':
                t = children[0]
                return t

            elif label == 'Add':
                t1 = children[0]
                v1 = evalTerm(env, t1)
                t2 = children[1]
                v2 = evalTerm(env, t2)
                return v1 + v2

            elif label == 'Multiply':
                t1 = children[0]
                v1 = evalTerm(env, t1)
                t2 = children[1]
                v2 = evalTerm(env, t2)
                return v1 * v2


            elif label == 'Variable':
                x = children[0]
                if x in env:
                    return env[x]
                else:
                    print(x + " is unbound")
                    exit()

            elif label == 'Int':
                f = children[0]

                v = evalTerm[env, f]
                if v == 'True':
                    return 1
                elif v == 'False':
                    return 0

            elif label == 'Parens':
                x = children[0]
                v = evalTerm(env, x)
                return v

    elif type(f) == Leaf:
        if f == 'True':
            return 'True'
        if f == 'False':
            return 'False'
```

When I test it by using:

```
evalTerm({}, {'Int': ['True']})
```

it gives an error:

> 'function' object is not subscriptable

How could I fix it?

Comment: By the way:in my code, I wrote:  Node = dict;  Leaf = str

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? For python, we need to see the exact indentation you're using.

Comment: Is the error message pointing to a specific line? The error is most likely there... Also include that `Node = dict`, `Leaf = str` thing in your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to say for sure without the full traceback, but most likely this is your problem:

```
v = evalTerm[env, f]
```

`evalTerm` is a recursive function that you would need to call (note the additional `()` instead of `[]` ):

```
v = evalTerm(env, f)
```

Square brackets `[ ]` in Python are used for [subscription](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) or indexing - that means, for example addressing a value in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) by its key, or an item in a [list](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) by its index.

If you get the exception `'foo' object is not subscriptable` that means that you tried to use subscription for an object of type `'foo'` that doesn't support it.