# while importing the data into python i am getting the following error

Tags: python

while importing the data into python i got the following error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-9f4ad3735626> in <module>()
----> 1 newwww = pd.read_csv["CaseStudy_MarketingCampaign (1)"]

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: @GrantShannon the issue is clear-cut, they're using `[]` and not `()` for a function call

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: 'function' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551996/error-function-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 0):

You are using [], which is for arrays. You want to use read_csv() for a function with parameters.

Comment: Still not sufficient to fix the error, they haven't given a file extension